# Como fazer um merge em uma branch que não está no repositório local?

Tags: git

Quando você não tem a branch local, mas quer mergear, o erro "not something we can merge" ocorre. O ideal é que se faça o `git checkout [nome da branch para merge]` que dá um fetch, e possibilitando o merge.

É possível buscar (fetch) a branch sem ter que dar um checkout, e efetuar o merge?

Isso ajudaria a não ter que commitar ou dar um "stash/shelve" no ambiente atual, e entrar com checkout na branch que precisa mergear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode referenciar a branch direto do remoto.

```sh
git fetch --all         # faz um fetch em todos os remotos
git merge origin/master # faz um merge referenciando o remoto origin, e não a branch local
```

Comment: Obrigado pelo apoio e resposta, através disso encontrei excelentes referencias por esse link para solução:

[git fetch](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/syncing/git-fetch)

Resumindo, minha necessidade era basicamente buscar uma branch específica de origin, e pode ser feito com: `git fetch <remote> <branch>`